# Outputting Javascript calculation to html

Tags: javascript, html

Hi might be a noob question but im still learning :)

Basically im trying to allow the user to input a number that gets multiplied up to 10 i then what to display the multiplications within the html as a list.

at the moment when i press the button to submit a number the output quickly flashes to the screen and doesn't remain

below is my code any help will be appreciated probably something silly !

```js
function TimesTable() {
  var number = document.getElementById('number').value;



  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var result = number * i;
    console.log(result);

  }

  document.getElementById("outPut").innerHTML = result;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lilita+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js"></script>
  <title>Times Tables</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Times Tables</h1>
    <p>Please Enter A number below to times</p>
    <form action="">
      Times: <input id="number" type="text" name="number1" size="3"><br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Print Time Table" onclick="TimesTable()">
    </form>
    <div id="outPut">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yep, that's because you're using type="submit"! So the form will try to go to your "action" when you press the button. Replace type="submit" with type="button"

Comment: For what you are doing, you don't even need the form at all. And, also yes, change your input(submit) to a <button>.

Comment: Alternatively there appears to be no reason that this is in a `<form>` at all.  If you're not submitting the form there's probably no good reason to have it.  You're allowed to use inputs and buttons outside a form.

Comment: okay thank you ! that fixed the flashing issue if i wanted to print out each calculation would I move document.getElementById("outPut").innerHTML = result; inside the loop ?

Comment: That would simply replace the innerHTML on every single iteration of the loop, so you would end up seeing the results of the last iteration of the loop.  I'm thinking you would want something like `+= result`.

Comment: Moving that inside the loop will mean that each time you get to that line, the inner html becomes the new result.  If you want to append instead, you could use += instead of =.  Also good job writing up this question; it's very clear and well formatted.

Comment: okay i have it printing to the console like 1 x 5 = 5 etc but i dont understand how to go abouting outputting this to the div at the moment?? any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

H. Figueiredo is correct, the input type should be "button. You also have a logic error in your javascript.

```
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var result = number * i;
  }
```

This block is overwriting the result value each iteration. So in the end, result will only be number * 10.

What you probably want to do is create a 'results' array and populate it with all of the elements. You can then pass that to your 'outPut' element.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other answers, if you are using a form, when submitting the form will refresh the page.

To disable the refresh, have the form provide the event call:

```
<form action=#" onsubmit="yourjsfunction(); return false">
```

That way your page won't refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `type="submit"` with `type="button"` to avoid submit the page.

```js
function TimesTable() {
  var number = document.getElementById('number').value;



  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var result = number * i;
    console.log(result);

  }

  document.getElementById("outPut").innerHTML = result;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lilita+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js"></script>
  <title>Times Tables</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Times Tables</h1>
    <p>Please Enter A number below to times</p>
    <form action="">
      Times: <input id="number" type="text" name="number1" size="3"><br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Print Time Table" onclick="TimesTable()">
    </form>
    <div id="outPut">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```